# Knockout custom bootstrap binding error with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, requirejs

I have a custom knockout binding for bootstrap tooltips and some times the page loads fine and some times I get this error being thrown in the binding.

> $(...).tooltip is not a function

I have set a break point in the section where this is happening and sometimes the jquery object doesn't have any bootstrap functions on it.  I can only assume that this is an issue with the timing of when the bootstrap library is loaded by require.  Like I said, it doesn't happen every time and it seems to happen much more often when I have the dev tools console open.

Here is my require config

```
requirejs.config({
    waitSeconds: 200,
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: "$.fn.tooltip"
        }
    },
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-1.11.3.min',
        bootstrap: 'bootstrap.min',
        moment: 'moment.min',
        knockout: 'knockout.min',
        appVM: 'appVM',
        custombindings: 'custombindings'
    }
});
```

And my binding

```
define(['knockout', 'jquery', 'bootstrap'], function (ko, $, bootstrap) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var local = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
                options = {};

            ko.utils.extend(options, ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip.options);
            ko.utils.extend(options, local);

            $(element).tooltip(options);  //Error thrown here

            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                $(element).tooltip("destroy");
            });
        },
        options: {
            'container': 'body',
            'delay': { 'show': 1000, 'hide': 100 },
            'animation': 'true'
        }
    };
});
```

My apply bindings

```
define(['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'appVM', 'knockout', 'domReady!'], 
    function(jquery, bootstrap, appVM, ko) {
    var vm = new appVM();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Comment: Do you have a similar define block around where you `applyBindings`? You want to be sure everything's loaded.

Comment: @RoyJ I edited my question.  I am loading bootstrap before the apply bindings.

Comment: Have you checked that `element` is a DOM element and not null or undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your `customBindings` to the dependencies list in the module which calls `ko.applyBindings`

```
define(['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'appVM', 'knockout', 'customBindings', 'domReady!'],
    function(jquery, bootstrap, appVM, ko) {
    var vm = new appVM();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```